# SQLITE: Multiple foreign key referenced to multiple table cascade delete

Tags: foreign-key, sqlite, delete, cascade

In SQLite I would like to delete parent table row and it has to delete all the related child tables. I have gone through all the questions in StackExchange and other websites but my query no where satisfied.

I have four tables.

```
TableA:
id, primary key
name

TableB:
id, primary key
issues,
tb_aid, #foreign key ref to TableA id
tb_cid, #foreign key ref to TableC id
tb_did, #foreign key ref to TableD id
tb_eid, #foreign key ref to TableE id

TableC:
id, primary key
column1,
tb_bid, #foreign key ref to TABLE B id

TableD:
id,
name

TableE
id,
name
```

I tried `JOIN` but unfortunately its not working in SQLite. I dont know how to use `TRIGGER`. Is it possible to use ON `CASCADE DELETE` for the above case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use on cascade delete

**Example**

Turn on FK Support

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON
```

Create sample data

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
id INTEGER primary key ,
name varchar
);
CREATE TABLE TableC
(
id INTEGER primary key,
name varchar
);
CREATE TABLE TableB
(
id INTEGER primary key,
issues varchar,
tb_aid INTEGER,   
tb_cid  INTEGER    ,
CONSTRAINT fk_TBLC
FOREIGN KEY (tb_cid)
REFERENCES TableC(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT fk_TBLA
FOREIGN KEY (tb_aid)
REFERENCES TableA(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
);
INSERT INTO TableA(id,name) VALUES(1,'test');
INSERT INTO TableC(id,name) VALUES(1,'test');
INSERT INTO TableB(id,issues,tb_aid,tb_cid) VALUES(1,'test',1,1);
```

Delete the value from TableA

```
DELETE FROM TableA where id = 1;
```

Select from tableB

```
SELECT * FROM TableB;
```

**Result**

> id    issues  tb_aid  tb_cid

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=06aa57cc6e7b7214d5a9decd5754d235)

You do have bidirectional FK's in your example, while I do not think it is a good design, you could use something like the DB Fiddle below.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=294cffbdb984354b4409972e535aa442)

Comment: @user2660409 no problem, glad it helped!